# Mysql connection pools aren't being freed up after each use; How to properly free up connection in Golang?

Tags: go

In my workplace we're migrating to a new website. One of the problems we have is that the urls on the new site are different than the ones in the old site. So my job is to create some kind of "mapper" that will act in front of the actual web server, parse it, see if it's one of the old urls, and if it does, redirect it to the new url. Otherwise, just forward the request as is.

Me being too optimistic, decided to make it in Golang because I heard it was fast. The problem is that I had no experience using the language prior to this one. I mean it's a very simple web server. So I reckon it should be easy to learn, right?

Anyway. Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
  "net/url"
    "net/http"
  "net/http/httputil"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
  "log"
  "path/filepath"
  "strconv"
  "strings"
)

//initiate db
var db *sql.DB

func main() {
  //load environment variables
  dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  envPath := filepath.Join(dir, ".env")
  godotenv.Load(envPath)

  //load connection
  db = dbConn()

  //set router
  router := mux.NewRouter()

  //set handleMapper as a handle to all routes
  router.HandleFunc("/{p:.*}", handleMapper)


  //set server, and stop server if there's any error.
  port := ":" + os.Getenv("MAPPERPORT")
  log.Panic(http.ListenAndServe(port, router))
}

//the main handler for all url
func handleMapper(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  //remove first '/' at the beginning of url path
  urlPath := r.URL.Path[1:]

  //prepare the sql statement to get new url from old url
  selectStmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT id, newPath FROM url_rewrites where oldPath = ?")
  if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err.Error())
  }

  //run the query
  row := selectStmt.QueryRow(urlPath);

  //scan the result, put the value of newPath in a variable with the same name
  var id int
  var newPath string
  noRowErr := row.Scan(&id, &newPath)

  //free up the db connection
  selectStmt.Close()

  //if we got "no row error", it means no need to redirect. Just forward it to the real webserver
  if noRowErr != nil {
    forwardRequest(w, r)
  //if a row is found, redirect it to the new url
  } else {
    returnRedirect(w, r, id, newPath)
  } 
}

func returnRedirect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, id int, newPath string) {
  insertStmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO redirect_logs (url_rewrite_id) values (?)")
  _, err = insertStmt.Query(id)
  if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err.Error())
  }

  //free up the db connection
  insertStmt.Close()

  newPath = os.Getenv("NEWDOMAIN") + newPath
  http.Redirect(w, r, newPath, 301)
}


func forwardRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  urlAsIs, err := url.Parse("http://" + os.Getenv("IPADDR") + ":" + os.Getenv("NEWPORT"))
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(urlAsIs)
  proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)

}

func dbConn() (db *sql.DB) {
    dbDriver := "mysql"
    dbHost := os.Getenv("DBHOST")
    dbUser := os.Getenv("DBUSERNAME")
    dbPass := os.Getenv("DBPASSWORD")
    dbName := os.Getenv("DBNAME")
    db, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbUser+":"+dbPass+"@tcp("+dbHost+")/"+dbName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err.Error())
    }

    dbMaxConnection, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("DBMAXCONNECTION"))
    if err != nil {
      log.Panic(err.Error())
    }
    db.SetMaxOpenConns(dbMaxConnection)

    return db
}
```

And it works! ...For 20 seconds. Then the website would timeout.

When I check inside mysql console, there are 149 connections from this app.

I'm guessing it's because I didn't close my connection properly. But how to do that? I did close the prepared statements (as seen in my code). And I thought the `QueryRow()` would automatically close after calling `Scan()`.

Then I read in the go database sql page (http://go-database-sql.org/surprises.html):

- Opening and closing databases can cause exhaustion of resources.
- Failing to read all rows or use rows.Close() reserves connections from the pool.
- Using Query() for a statement that doesn't return rows will reserve a connection from the pool.
- Failing to be aware of how prepared statements work can lead to a lot of extra database activity.

I suspect that because the QueryRow doesn't always return a row, it doesn't free up connection pool. What is the proper way to free it?

Or is there something else that I missed in my code?

Comment: Why are you using prepared statements when you do not reuse them? The whole raison d'être of a prepared statement is to prepare it _once_ and execute it multiple times. You `db.Prepare` afresh on each request. Don't do that. This has no advantage. Either prepare your two statements once (e.g. in main) or just do db.{Query,Exec,QueryRow}. Also: Close your rows.

Comment: ah okay, thanks, I'll move the db.Prepare to main. But I didn't use any Query(), which rows should I close?

Comment: Use `defer db.Close()` in order to close the connection once necessary. Use `fasthttp` as webserver